# How to create a "Pair" function to match against a string list?

Tags: f#

I was doing an exercise on [F# Wiki Book on List](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Lists) (scroll to the bottom) to create a `Pair` method.

I was able to pair a integer list without problem but an F# exception was thrown for a string list.  It is just too cryptic for me to decipher what the exception means for an F# beginner like me.

Here is my initial attempt to implementing `Pair` on `fsi.exe`

```
> let pair l =
-     let rec loop acc = function
-         | [] -> acc
-         | (hd1 :: hd2 :: tl) -> loop ((hd1, hd2) :: acc) tl
-     List.rev(loop [] l)
-
- printfn "%A" ([1..10] |> pair)
- printfn "%A" ([ "one"; "two"; "three"; "four"; "five" ] |> pair);;

      let rec loop acc = function
  -----------------------^

stdin(2,24): warning FS0025: Incomplete pattern matches on this expression. 
    For example, the value '[_]' will not be matched

val pair : 'a list -> ('a * 'a) list

[(1, 2); (3, 4); (5, 6); (7, 8); (9, 10)]
Microsoft.FSharp.Core.MatchFailureException: 
Exception of type 'Microsoft.FSharp.Core.MatchFailureException' was thrown.
   at FSI_0002.clo@2T.Invoke(List`1 acc, List`1 _arg1)
   at FSI_0002.pair[T](List`1 l)
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0002>.$FSI_0002._main()
stopped due to error
```

So `Pair` does work on integer version 
and the function signature

```
val pair : 'a list -> ('a * 'a) list
```

indicates that `Pair` operates on a generic list.
**Question:** Then why would `Pair` not work on a string list?

**[ANSWER]** (my version) 
Simply returning accumulated list for `else` case (_) did the trick.
And the warning is taken care of, as well.

```
let pair l =
    let rec loop acc = function
//        | [] -> acc
        | (hd1 :: hd2 :: tl) -> loop ((hd1, hd2) :: acc) tl
        | _ -> acc
    List.rev(loop [] l)

printfn "%A" ([1..10] |> pair)
printfn "%A" ([ "one"; "two"; "three"; "four"; "five" ] |> pair)
```

**[EDIT2]** Well, I will also post my version of `Unpair` for completeness.

```
let unpair l = [for (a,b) in l do yield! a :: b :: []]
```

Here is somewhat flawed benchmarking using solution version against that of mine for 1 million item lists

```
#light

open System;

let pn l = printfn "%A" l

let duration f = 
    let startTime = DateTime.Now;
    let returnValue = f()
    let endTime = DateTime.Now;
    printfn "Duration (ms): %f" (endTime - startTime).TotalMilliseconds
    returnValue

let ll =  [for a in 1..1000000 do yield (a)]
let tl = [for a in 1..1000000 do yield (a,a)]


let pair1 l =
    let rec loop acc = function
        | [] | [_] -> List.rev acc
        | h1 :: h2 :: tl -> loop ((h1, h2) :: acc) tl
    loop [] l

let unpair1 l =
    let rec loop acc = function
        | [] -> List.rev acc
        | (h1, h2) :: tl -> loop (h2 :: h1 :: acc) tl
    loop [] l

let pair2 l =
    let rec loop acc = function
        | (hd1 :: hd2 :: tl) -> loop ((hd1, hd2) :: acc) tl
        | _ | [_] -> acc
    List.rev(loop [] l)

    let unpair2 l = [for (a,b) in l do yield! a :: b :: []]

pn(duration (fun() -> ll |> pair1))
pn(duration (fun() -> tl |> unpair1))

pn(duration (fun() -> ll |> pair2))
pn(duration (fun() -> tl |> unpair2))
```

Benchmark Result:

```
Solution version
PAIR -> Duration (ms): 255.000000
UNPAIR -> Duration (ms): 840.000000

My version
PAIR -> Duration (ms): 220.000000
UNPAIR -> Duration (ms): 1624.000000
```

Comment: By the way, Wiki book lists a solution for implementing "Pair" but I  decided NOT to cheat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think your version of Pair would work on a list of an odd number of anything.  You happen to test an even number of ints and a odd number of strings.  I think your second argument to match implies a list of at least two members.  So you break off 2 break off 2 and get to a list with 1 element and none of your conditions match.

[_] is a 1 item list with anything in it.  You must provide a predicate that matches it.

Comment: I just returned whatever the accumulated value is returned for "else" case.  It works! Thanks - Answer is posted in the question.